# Why does my application 'randomly' stop updating the tables in my database in MVC until I stop debugging and then start again?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm having this strange issue in MVC where the application is working fine, and then as I run through a few views with a post request, the database does not update. I don't receive any kind of error; the application behaves *almost* as it normally would, just without actually updating the row of a table associated with that particular item.

I have discovered that if I stop visual studio from running/debugging this application, then run it again, I can successfully update the tables once again. What could be causing this issue? I can reproduce this issue with the following setup.

**Model**

*Accounts.cs*

```
    public partial class Accounts
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string AccountName { get; set; }
        public string Validated { get; set; }
        public string ReValidated { get; set; }

        public virtual Accounts_AE Accounts_AE { get; set; }
    }
```

*Accounts_AE.cs*

```
    public partial class Accounts_AE
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string DateNoted { get; set; }
        public string ActionTaken { get; set; }

        public virtual Accounts Accounts { get; set; }
    }
```

**View Model**

*DatabaseViewModel.cs*

```
namespace AccountManagement.ViewModel
{
    public class DatabaseViewModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<Accounts> DBAccounts { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Accounts_AE> DBAccountsAE { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**View**

*Index.cshtml*

```
@model AccountManagement.ViewModel.DatabaseViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>


<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            AccountName
        </th>
        <th>
            Action
        </th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model.DBAccounts)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AccountName)
            </td>           
            <td>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="ActionAway(@item.ID)">Perform Check</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal1">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content" id="mymodalContent" style="padding:15px">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal2">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content" id="mymodalContent2" style="padding:15px">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    var ActionAway = function (theid) {
        var url = "/DB/Validate?id=" + theid;

        $('#mymodalContent').load(url, function () {
            $('#myModal1').modal("show");

        })
    }

</script>

<script>
    var ActionAway2 = function (theid) {
        var url = "/DB/Change?id=" + theid;

        $('#mymodalContent2').load(url, function () {
            $('#myModal2').modal("show");

        })
    }
</script>
```

*ConfirmF.cshtml*

```
@model AccountManagement.Models.Accounts_AE

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "View";
    Layout = null;
}

<div class="modal-header">
    <a href="#" class="close">&times;</a>
    <h3 class="modal-title">Confirm Action</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body" id="myModalBodyDiv1">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td width="50%">
                <table class="table">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Date Flagged</th>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.DateNoted)
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnSave">Confirm</button></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td width="50%">
                <table class="table">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Account Name</th>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.DB_Accounts.AccountName)</td>
                    </tr>                    
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>


    @section Scripts {
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    }

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btnSave").click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    success: function () {
                        $("#myModal").modal("hide");
                        location.reload();

                    }
                })
            })

        })
    </script>
```

*Flagged.cshtml*

```
@model AccountManagement.ViewModel.DatabaseViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <tr>
        <th>
            AccountName
        </th>
        <th>
            Action Account
        </th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model.DBAccounts)
    {
        <tr id="row_@item.ID">
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AccountName)
            </td>
            <td>
                Action Account
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Date Flagged:
            </th>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.DBAccountsAE.Where(m => m.ID == item.ID).First().DateNoted)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Action Taken
            </th>            
        </tr>
    }

</table>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal1">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</a>
                <h3 class="modal-title">Action This Account</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="myModalBodyDiv1">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


@section Scripts{
    <script>
        var ActionAway = function (theid) {
            var url = "/DB/Edit?id=" + theid;

            $('#myModalBodyDiv1').load(url, function () {
                $('#myModal1').modal("show");

            })
        }

    </script>

}
```

*Edit.cshtml*

```
@model AccountManagement.Models.Accounts_AE

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "View";
    Layout = null;
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.DateNoted)

        <table>
            <tr>
                <td width="50%">
                    <table class="table">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Date Flagged</th>
                            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.DateNoted)
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <th>Action Taken</th>
                            <td>@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.ActionTaken, new { @class = "form-control", rows = "5" })</td>
                        </tr>

                    </table>
                </td>
                <td width="50%">
                    <table class="table">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Account Name</th>
                            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Accounts.AccountName)</td>
                        </tr>                        
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnSave"/>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
}


@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnSave").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                success: function () {
                    $("#myModal").modal("hide");

                }
            })
        })

    })
</script>
```

**Controller**

*DBController.cs*

```
namespace AccountManagement.Controllers
{
    public class DBController : Controller
    {
        private AccountEntities db = new AccountEntities();

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            DatabaseViewModel DBVM = new DatabaseViewModel();
            DBVM.DBAccounts = db.Accounts.Where(x => x.Validated == null).ToList();
            return View("Index", DBVM);
        }

        public ActionResult Flagged()
        {
            DatabaseViewModel DBVM = new DatabaseViewModel();
            DBVM.DBAccounts = db.Accounts.Where(x => x.Validated == "F" || (x.ReValidated == "R" && x.Validated == null)).ToList();
            DBVM.DBAccountsAE = db.Accounts_AE.ToList();
            return View("Flagged", DBVM);
        }

        public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Accounts_AE actionableEvents = db.Accounts_AE.Find(id);
            if (actionableEvents == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(actionableEvents);
        }

        //Edit Save
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit(Accounts_AE actionableEvents)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                DB_Accounts dB_Accounts = db.DB_Accounts.Where(x => x.ID == actionableEvents.ID).First();
                dB_Accounts.Validated = null;
                dB_Accounts.ReValidated = "R";
                db.Entry(dB_Accounts).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Flagged");
            }
            return View(actionableEvents);
        }


        public ActionResult Validate(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            DB_Accounts dB_Accounts = db.DB_Accounts.Find(id);
            DB_Accounts_AE dB_Accounts_AE = db.DB_Accounts_AE.Find(id);            
            dB_Accounts_AE.ReviewedBy = User.Identity.Name.ToString();
            dB_Accounts_AE.DateNoted = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd MMM yyyy");
            dB_Accounts.Validated = "F";



            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(dB_Accounts_AE).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.Entry(dB_Accounts).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
            }

            return View("ConfirmF", dB_Accounts_AE);
        }


        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

To reproduce the issue, I start at the Index page. I click on the "Perform Check" button, which brings up a modal pop-up (ConfirmF). I click the "Confirm" button on the popup, and then the item in question disappears from the page. I then go to the Flagged page. From here, I click on the "Action" button, save it, and then go back to the Index page. The item is has now re-appeared on the page.

What *should* happen at this point is when I click on "Perform Check", the item should disappear like it did before. However, nothing actually happens. When I debug the program, I discovered that it's not even hitting the controller! What is going on here?

To explain my program in a nutshell, the items on the Index page are filtered from a table. Once you click the "Perform Check" button, it changes a value (from NULL) in a table for that row so that the item is no longer included in the filter. When you Action it in the Flagged view, it changes the value back to NULL so that it shows up in the Index view once more. Unfortunately, at this point, you cannot repeat these steps as the "Perform Check" button will no longer work to update the table (or hit the controller).

If I stop debugging the program, then start it back up, I can successfully use the "Perform Check" button. Also, if I start the program and go to the Flagged page to Action an item, and then go back to the Index page, I can also successfully use the "Perform Check" button.

In other words, if do Index -> Flagged -> Index, "Perform Check" will fail. If I do Flagged -> Index, it will succeed. What on earth am I doing wrong here? I would greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: When you debug, does the bebugger hit: db.SaveChanges(); and it still doesn't write to the database? I mean, is there a chance the code it taking another path when you THINK it is actually hitting the db.SaveChanges(); line?

Comment: Thank you for the reply! If we are looking at the Index -> Flagged -> Index pattern to generate the error, db.SaveChanges() will indeed hit on the first Index and Flagged View. However, on the third Index view, the controller isn't even being hit, hence Save.Changes() is not being used. I can't seem to figure out why this controller is not being hit. Any suggestions on how I can approach finding out?